Is this actor-critic algorithm correct?
See slide 92 here: https://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture14.pdf

I did not understand the expression for critic in update of $\Delta \phi$ and also why is it updated at the end of inner for-loop? Where is the initialization for $\Delta \phi$?

In S&B RL book page 332 pseudocode for one-step actor-critic method with 2 nested loops, both policy and critic parameters could be initialized arbitrarily, and for example they're both initialized to $0$ vectors in the pseudocode. And $\alpha, \beta$ above are learning rate step size for policy and critic parameters, respectively.
However, your reference notations are not based on one-step but based on accumulated Monte Carlo simulated return of the m-th trajectory under the current (stochastic) policy, therefore, following your reference’s notations, policy and critic parameters can still both be initialized as $0$ vectors, but there’s actually no need to initialize $\Delta \phi$ as it’s computed only based on the advantage functions $A^i_t$ after your quoted two inner loops. The reason why $\Delta \theta$ is initialized to $0$ after the outermost episodic loop is that it needs to be reset to $0$ at the start of each episode after accumulation in the two inner loops while $\Delta \phi$ is not accumulating there thus no need to reset or initialize.
